# transform an XML file by XSL1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to modify an XML file according to the element 'identifier' and 'items' of menu.

1. if the 'identifier' of a menu is exist in another menu's items in input XML file, the menu context should be copied below the parent menu in output XML file, and the order should be same with the parent's items.
2. menu's element of 'label' should be changed to 'level_xx'.'xx' is the level number, for detail please refer to the excel capture.

Can any one please help me how do I achieve this using XSL1.0.

**Input XML file**:

```
<input>
    <menu>
        <identifier>1</identifier>
        <label>"1"</label>
        <items>
            <item>2</item>
            <item>3</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>2</identifier>
        <label>"2"</label>
        <items>
            <item>21</item>
            <item>22</item>
            <item>3</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>3</identifier>
        <label>"3"</label>
        <items>
            <item>31</item>
            <item>32</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>21</identifier>
        <label>"21"</label>
        <items>
            <item>211</item>
            <item>212</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>22</identifier>
        <label>"22"</label>
        <items>
            <item>221</item>
            <item>222</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>31</identifier>
        <label>"31"</label>
        <items>
            <item>311</item>
            <item>312</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>32</identifier>
        <label>"32"</label>
        <items>
            <item>321</item>
            <item>322</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
</input>
```

**Output XML file**:

```
<input>
    <menu>
        <identifier>1</identifier>
        <level_01>"1"</level_01>
        <items>
            <item>2</item>
            <item>3</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>2</identifier>
        <level_02>"2"</level_02>
        <items>
            <item>21</item>
            <item>22</item>
            <item>3</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>21</identifier>
        <level_03>"21"</level_03>
        <items>
            <item>211</item>
            <item>212</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>22</identifier>
        <level_03>"22"</level_03>
        <items>
            <item>221</item>
            <item>222</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>3</identifier>
        <level_03>"3"</level_03>
        <items>
            <item>31</item>
            <item>32</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>31</identifier>
        <level_04>"31"</level_04>
        <items>
            <item>311</item>
            <item>312</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>32</identifier>
        <level_04>"32"</level_04>
        <items>
            <item>321</item>
            <item>322</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>3</identifier>
        <level_02>"3"</level_02>
        <items>
            <item>31</item>
            <item>32</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>31</identifier>
        <level_03>"31"</level_03>
        <items>
            <item>311</item>
            <item>312</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>32</identifier>
        <level_03>"32"</level_03>
        <items>
            <item>321</item>
            <item>322</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
</input>
```

[the **level info** of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id5eM.png)

Comment: It is not clear where the `levelNN` values are supposed to come from: can they be copied from the existing  `label`? Or do they need to derived from the actual level?

Comment: **levelNN** is the actual level. and the **value of levelNN** is copied from the existing label.

Comment: Your input XML is not well-formed! And it makes no sense that `<item>3</item>` is a descendant of both `<identifier>1</identifier>` and `<identifier>2</identifier>`.

Comment: In this case where the same **<item>3</item>** appears in different **<identifier>**, the format is correct. It's a real use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input XML actually looks like this:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <menu>
        <identifier>1</identifier>
        <label>"1"</label>
        <items>
            <item>2</item>
            <item>3</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>2</identifier>
        <label>"2"</label>
        <items>
            <item>21</item>
            <item>22</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>3</identifier>
        <label>"3"</label>
        <items>
            <item>31</item>
            <item>32</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>21</identifier>
        <label>"21"</label>
        <items>
            <item>211</item>
            <item>212</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>22</identifier>
        <label>"22"</label>
        <items>
            <item>221</item>
            <item>222</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>31</identifier>
        <label>"31"</label>
        <items>
            <item>311</item>
            <item>312</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <identifier>32</identifier>
        <label>"32"</label>
        <items>
            <item>321</item>
            <item>322</item>
        </items>
    </menu>
</input>
```

you could adapt the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879136/sort-an-xml-file-into-a-tree-structure-by-xsl-1-0) and do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="menu" use="identifier" />
<xsl:key name="parent" match="menu" use="items/item" />

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="menu[not(key('parent', identifier))]">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="menu">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="identifier"/>
        <xsl:element name="level_{format-number($level, '00')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="label" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="items"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', items/item)">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

If you need the child `menu` elements to be listed in the same order as the `item` elements are within `items`, then change this part:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', items/item)">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

to:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', .)">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: For the assumed XML file, the 'xx' in the element "level_xx" should be the actual level number.  for example, the 'xx' of <identifier>21<identifier> is '03', the element should be <level_03>.

Comment: Well, isn't it? You may have missed an edit of my answer.

Comment: sorry, I just missed the edited. It has been adjusted.  Another problem,  base on my input XML file, In the output file the <identifier>2</identifier> below menu should be in the order '21->22->3', but now is '3->21->22'.

Comment: The child items are listed in the order in which they appear in the XML document. If it is important to to list them in the same order as they appear inside `items`, something will need to be changed. Is it really important?

Comment: Yes, this will determine the item show order in a pc software.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.